# Is $p=257$ prime in $\mathbb Z[\sqrt{ -92}]$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification, ring-theory, ideals, maximal-and-prime-ideals

> Is $p=257$ prime in $\mathbb Z[\sqrt{ -92}]$?

My thoughts: We have $\mathbb Z[\sqrt{ -92}]\cong\mathbb Z[X]/(X^2+92)$, so $\mathbb Z[\sqrt{ -92}]/(p)\cong\mathbb Z_{257}[X]/(X^2+92)$. Then $p$ is prime if $(p)$ is prime and $(p)$ is prime iff the ring above is an integral domain. But $X^2+92$ is not irreducible over $\mathbb Z_{257}$ since the equation $a^2\equiv 165\bmod 257$ has a solution (the Jacoby-Symbol is $\left(\frac{165}{257}\right)=1$). So the ring above is not an integral domain and $p$ is not prime.

Comment: Your approach looks fine.

Comment: Alright, I wasn't sure about the $(p)$ prime $\Leftrightarrow$ $R/(p)$ is an integral domain and $(p)$ prime $\implies p$ prime.

Comment: $(p)$ is a prime ideal if and only if $p$ is a prime element. This is not hard to show from definition.

Comment: In fact, $(57+\sqrt{-94})(57-\sqrt{-94})=3341=257\cdot 13$ but clearly neither factor is divisible by $257$.